# Changing PDO to Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I want to convert PDO code to mysqli and having some problem. I'm still new at this and I really don't understand PDO completely.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO gender(gender) VALUES (:gender)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(array('gender' => $_POST["gender"]));
$count = $statement->rowCount();
```

This is far I got.

```
$statement = $db->prepare ($query);;
$statement = array('gender' => $_POST["gender"]);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
$statement = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
```

Comment: Opinion: PDO is the better SQL wrapper, going to mysqli is a step backwards. Of course I don't know the specifics why you have to do it...

Comment: @MiK that's more a fact if anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try this version:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO gender(gender) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["gender"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

You need to use the `bind_param()` function to bind parameters to your `mysqli` statement.  Note that `mysqli`, unlike PDO, does *not* support named parameters.  Instead, just use `?` as a placeholder to which you bind your actual value later on.